# How to get TRIM support on XP with a Crucial RealSSD C300?

Tags: windows-xp, ssd, trim

I have seen that Intel has a tool that gives Trim support to older OSes running on Intel SSD's.

We are rolling with Crucial SSD's, and everything is XP.

Is there a utility or trick?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I recommend writing backups of the rollout images, and refreshing the drives periodically. TRIM is not going to be supported on XP anytime soon.</strike>

I take it back. It looks like Intel has a [utility](http://www.intel.com/pressroom/archive/releases/2009/20091026comp.htm), as you pointed out.

> The firmware upgrade and Intel SSD
>   Optimizer use the Windows* 7 ATA Data
>   Set Management Command (known as Trim)
>   to help keep the Intel SSD running at
>   continued high performance. In
>   addition, the SSD Toolbox and
>   Optimizer also allow the respective
>   enhancements to work with Windows* XP
>   and Vista* operating systems.

And apparently Crucial supports user-managed garbage collection on XP and Vista too. I found this information on this page:

http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx

> Crucial Wiper tool for user-initiated
>   Garbage Collection. (For use with
>   Windows XP and Vista only.)

Comment: Annnnd, my question is: What about Crucial SSD's?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Unverified claim on http://forums.pcper.com/showthread.php?t=470879: "Checked on the Crucial forums, and they don't recommend using the Crucial Wiper Tool at all on the C300 drives, as apparently it is not needed, and the possibility that if it is used, could mess up the drive, which I don't want."

Comment: That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The C300 supports [garbage collection](http://www.forum.crucial.com/t5/Solid-State-Drives-SSD/Does-c300-has-garbage-collection/td-p/10695), which means the drive collects old blocks while it is idle.